# Indesign CC script to apply paragraph styles to multiple paragraphs

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an Indesign document with the following structure:

> paragraph 1 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>
> paragraph 2 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>
> paragraph 3 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>
> paragraph 4 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>
> paragraph 5 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
>
> . . . and so on...

Now I need to leave the first paragraph as is but apply paragraph styles to all the subsequent paragraphs in the following pattern:

> paragraph 2: style A
>
> paragraph 3: style B
>
> paragraph 4: style A
>
> paragraph 5: style B
>
> . . . and so on (*alternating pattern*)...

I know this can be automated using scripts and I also know a bit of programming in general (JavaScript) but I have no idea how to go about doing this in Indesign. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this script:

provided you have a text frame and you referenced it to a variable myFrame

```
    for (i=0; i < myFrame.paragraphs.length; i++)
    {
       if ( i%2 == 0 )
       {
        myFrame.parentStory.paragraphs[i].appliedParagraphStyle = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.item('Style B);
       }
       else
       {
        myFrame.parentStory.paragraphs[i].appliedParagraphStyle = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.item('Style A);
       }    

    }
```

Save it as a script in scripts folder and run from the scripts panel. You will need to add frame referencing.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It works. One last question while we're at it: How do you reference the style if it's grouped inside a styles folder? I have a group called Entry containing the style named Head. I tried Entry:Head, Entry(Head), Entry/Head...none of them worked.

Comment: You are looking for ParagraphStyleGroup which has paragraphStyles property. You can't call your objects directly by name without referencing them first. I strongly recommend, check this link: http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html ( Thanks, Johgware). This will give you InDesign DOM and addresses different InDesign versions

Comment: This should work: app.activeDocument.paragraphStyleGroups.item('Entry').paragraphStyles.item('Head')